# C# Reflection to match Type List<T> where T IsSubClass(Foo)

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I have a class that contains properties of `List<T>`.  Some of these properties, T is of a Class that inherits from a Class, say Foo.

```cs
public class Foo {}
public class MyTypeA : Foo {}
public class MyTypeB : Foo {}

// Not : Foo
public class MyTypeC {}

public class Bar 
{
    // I can Match these
    public MyTypeA PropA { get; set; }
    public MyTypeB PropB { get; set; }

    // How can I match these based on IsSubclassOf(Foo)
    public List<MyTypeA> PropListA { get; set; }
    public List<MyTypeB> PropListB { get; set; }

    // Do not match the props below
    public MyTypeC PropC { get; set; }
    public List<MyTypeC> PropListC { get; set; }
    public List<string> PropListString { get; set; }

}
```

I'm already successfully matching properties that are a subclass of `Foo` as shown below.

```cs
foreach (var oProp in T.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    // Find Prop : Foo
    if( oProp.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf( typeof(Foo) ) )
    {
        // Add Property to dictionary
        aPropInheritType.Add(
            oProp.Name, 
            oProp
        );
    }

    // Match List<T>  where T : Foo
    // How do I test for Generic List that's Type T is a subclass 
    // of the class Foo ?

}
```

I see there are a number of Generic Properties of the Type class but haven't been able to get the Type of the Generic List to then test against IsSubclassOf(Foo).

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293905/reflection-getting-the-generic-parameters-from-a-system-type-instance

Comment: Go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42892f65.aspx and search for "generic"

Comment: Do you need a positive result for subclass of `List<T>` (for example `ObservableCollection<T>`), or for `List<T> where T : Foo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test if a property has return type `List<T>`, use next code:

```
Type returnType = oProp.PropertyType;
if(returnType.IsGenericType && 
   returnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>) &&
   typeof(Foo).IsAssignableFrom(returnType.GetGenericArguments()[0]))
{
   //property is of type List<T>, where T is derived from Foo
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Ilya!

Is there any benefit in using IsAssignableFrom over :

GetGenericArguments()[0].IsSubclassOf(typeof(Foo))

Comment: @hokapoka yes, `typeof(Foo).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Foo))` will return false, while `IsAssignableFrom` will return true. In your case you probably need `IsAssignableFrom`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little gem I stole from the Microsoft framework (I think it was in the EF binaries).

```
    private static Type GetTypeOfList(PropertyInfo changedMember)
    {
        var listType = from i in changedMember.PropertyType.GetInterfaces()
                       where i.IsGenericType
                       let generic = i.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                       where generic == typeof (IEnumerable<>)
                       select i.GetGenericArguments().Single();
        return listType.SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

You just need to test for

```
    Type listType = ...
    var tInListType = GetTypeOfList(listType);
    return tInListType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Foo));
```