# How can I find the attributes of a generic class in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following classes:

```
[Msg(Value = "YaaY")]
public class PersonContainer<T>  where T : new()
{
   ...
}


public class HappyPerson
{
   ...
}

[Msg(Value = "NaaY")]
public class SadPerson
{
   ...
}
```

Using the following method I can get the attributes of the "PersonContainer":

```
public void GetMsgVals(object personContainer)
{
    var info = personContainer.GetType();

    var attributes = (MsgAttribute[])info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MsgAttribute), false);
    var vals= attributes.Select(a => a.Value).ToArray();        
}
```

However I only get the attribute of "PersonContainer" (which is "YaaY") how can I get the atrributes of `T (HappyPerson [if any] or SadPerson["NaaY"])` at runtime without knowing what T is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reflection - Getting the generic parameters from a System.Type instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293905/reflection-getting-the-generic-parameters-from-a-system-type-instance)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get generic argument's type and then it's attributes:

```
var info = personContainer.GetType();

if (info.IsGenericType)
{
     var attributes = (MsgAttribute[])info.GetGenericArguments()[0]
                      .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MsgAttribute), false);
}
```

Edit: `GetGenericArguments` returns a `Type` array so my first call to `GetType` was unnecessary and I remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the generic type arguments to get their attributes:

```
var info = personContainer.GetType();
foreach (var gta in info.GenericTypeArguments)
{
    // gta.GetCustomAttributes(...)
}
```