# Get Type and Pass it as an Argument

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I have the following stored procedure DB.GetData() that returns a result of type:

```
IEnumerable<GetData_Result>
```

From the DB.GetData(), how to get the Data Type of the IEnumerable, which in this case GetDataResult_Result, and then pass it as SomeType_Result as follow:

```
  var model = new SomeViewModel() {
     var names = typeof(SomeType_Result).GetProperties().Select(i => i.Name);
       }
```

Comment: I think Jon Skeet has answered a very similar question here that may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293905/reflection-getting-the-generic-parameters-from-a-system-type-instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Type.GetGenericArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx)

```
var argumentType = IEnumerable<GetData_Result>.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

var model = new SomeViewModel() 
{
    var names = argumentType.GetProperties().Select(i => i.Name);
 }
```

Comment: When trying somoething like this: GetData_Result argumentType = IEnumerable<GetData_Result>.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] I get an error that I "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Type' to 'GetData_Result'

Comment: `GetGenericArguments` returns a `Type[]`, not an instance of the type. When selecting the `0 index` you get back a `Type` object, which is what you want