# How To Get The <T> Of SomeClass<T> When SomeClass Is Passed As A Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, model-binding

I'm trying to model bind using a model bind provider.

When the `GetBinder` method is hit I want to serve up a model binder based on what is passed in.

I have a generic model `IBaseModel<T> where T : IEntity`.

I can grab the `BaseModel` from the type but what i really want is the `<T>` on the `BaseModel<T>` which is an `IEntity`.

```
public IModelBinder GetBinder(Type modelType)
{
    Type baseModel = modelType.GetInterface(typeof(IBaseModel<>).Name);

     if (baseModel != null)
     {
         if (baseModel.IsGenericType)
         {
            //want to get <T> (IEntity) here.        
         }
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reflection - Getting the generic parameters from a System.Type instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293905/reflection-getting-the-generic-parameters-from-a-system-type-instance)

Comment: Thanks Chris thats exactly what I needed. I wasn't sure how to word my question which is why the answer passed me by.

Comment: That's cool. As you say its not easy to know what to search for. I knew they were called generic parameters so was able to get there immediately. :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to get the type of the generic parameter you can try this:

```
    public static Type GetBinder(Type modelType)
    {
        Type baseModel = modelType.GetInterface(typeof (IBaseModel<>).Name);

        if (baseModel != null)
        {
            if (baseModel.IsGenericType)
            {
                var interfacesTypes = modelType.GetInterfaces();
                var typeGeneric = interfacesTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsGenericTypeDefinition);
                if (typeGeneric != null)
                {
                    return typeGeneric.GetGenericArguments().First();
                }

            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public interface IBaseModel<T> where T : IEntity
    {

    }

    public class Musica : IBaseModel<Artista>
    {

    }

    public class Artista : IEntity
    {

    }
```