# Reflect the returnType of an async method

Tags: c#, async-await, reflection, aop, castle-dynamicproxy

Below is the code for an interceptor i wish to use for implementing a cacheprovider. I need to determine the return type of the method that will be invoked. This is pretty straight forward when the method invoked is synchronous. However most of the methods i'm encountering are async, they are returning a Task.

How can I use reflection to figure out the return type of the async methods?

```
public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
    try
    {
        if (invocation.Method.Name.StartsWith("Retrieve"))
        {
            var returnType = invocation.Method.ReturnType;
            if (returnType.IsGenericType &&
                returnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (Task<>))
            {
                var returnTypeOfTheTask = returnType.NeedSomeHelpHere();
            }
        }
        _circuitBreaker.Execute(invocation);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: See [this for getting the type parameters out of a generic type instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293905/reflection-getting-the-generic-parameters-from-a-system-type-instance).

Comment: Just try `var returnTypeOfTheTask = returnType.GenericTypeArguments[0];`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either

```
var returnTypeOfTheTask = returnType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

or

```
var returnTypeOfTheTask = returnType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
```

Which one you will use depends mostly on the platforms that you need to support (e.g. the first option exists since .NET 2.0 but is not supported in Modern UI, while the second option does not exist in .NET 4.0). I would recommend using the second method if both would work for your needs.

Comment: thank you, this works like a charm, i went with the second method

Answer (score 0):

With what I learned above, I created a method that drills all the way into the type hierarchy until I find a Type that is no longer generic.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the output type of the given method.
    /// 1. Get the method info using reflection.
    /// 2. Check if the method is an async method by calling the `IsAwait()` method.
    /// 3. If the method is an async method, get the return type using the `ReturnType` property.
    ///     a. Check if the return type is a generic type by calling the `IsGenericType` property.
    ///     b. If the return type is a generic type, get the generic arguments using the `GetGenericArguments` method.
    ///     c. Continue repeating #3 until the return type is no longer Generic.
    /// 4. If the method is not async then get the return type using the `ReturnType` property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="runType"></param>
    /// <param name="methodName"></param>
    /// <param name="methodParameterFQNs"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Type GetOutputType(
        Type runType,
        string methodName,
        List<string> methodParameterFQNs)
    {
        Type result = null;

        MethodInfo methodInfo =
            GetMethodByParameterMatch(
                runType, methodName, methodParameterFQNs);

        if (methodInfo.IsAwait())
        {
            result = methodInfo.ReturnType;

            if (result.IsGenericType)
            {
                while (result.IsGenericType)
                {
                    Type[] genericArguments = result.GetGenericArguments();

                    if (genericArguments.Length > 0)
                    {
                        result = genericArguments[0];
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = methodInfo.ReturnType;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = methodInfo.ReturnType;
        }

        return result;
    }
```