# How to retrieve generic argument with reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, interface

If i have some class like this

```
interface IDeclaration<T> {...}
```

how should i implement check if instance of my particular class derived from `IDeclaration<T>` and if so - what is the type `T` in our particular case.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reflection - Getting the generic parameters from a System.Type instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293905/reflection-getting-the-generic-parameters-from-a-system-type-instance)

Answer (score 1):

`IDeclaration` is an interface, not a class. Classes can *implement* this interface, not *derive* from it.

To check whether a particular object implements the `IDeclaration<T>` interface, you could call the `GetInterfaces` method on that instance type and search for that particular interface like this:

```
var instance = ...

var @interface =
    instance.GetType()
        .GetInterfaces()
        .FirstOrDefault(i =>
            i.IsGenericType &&
            i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IDeclaration<>));

bool is_IDeclaration = @interface != null;
```

To get the generic type parameter (`T`), you can use the `GetGenericArguments` method like this:

```
if (is_IDeclaration)
{
    var typeof_T = @interface.GetGenericArguments()[0];
}
```