# Is it possible to downcast a variable in an expression tree to a known generic derivation closed by Expression.Parameter(typeof(Type))?

Tags: c#, expression-trees, linq-expressions

I have an `Expression.Call` which uses `Expression.Parameter(typeof(Type))` to return an instance of type `SomeType`, which is in fact a derived class `SomeType<T>` with a field `SomeField` of type `T` where `T` is the parameter value.

Is it possible to construct a `LambdaExpression<Func<Type,object>>` that can be compiled to return the `SomeField` field value? ( Aside from creating expressions to call `FieldInfo.GetValue` through expressions ! Or through a create method that provides the type as parameter or generic parameter.)

```
public class SomeType
{
    public static SomeType Create(Type tType)
    {
        return (SomeType)typeof(SomeType<>).MakeGenericType(tType)
            .GetConstructor(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { tType }, null)
            .Invoke(new object[] { Activator.CreateInstance(tType) });
    }
}
public class SomeType<T> : SomeType where T:new()
{
    internal SomeType(T someField)
    {
        SomeField = someField;
    }
    public T SomeField;
}

public class GetFieldValue{
   public object NormalGetFieldValue(Type t){
        var someType = SomeType.Create(t);
        return someType.GetType().GetField("SomeField").GetValue(someType);
   }
   private Func<Type,object> compiledLambdaExpression;
   public object UseCompiledLamda(Type t){
        return compiledLambdaExpression(t);
   }
   public void How_Do_I_Create_Compiled_LambdaExpression????(){
      //of course can do the following
      //(t)=>{ //the code in NormalGetFieldValue }
      // or Delegate.CreateDelegate

      //Is it possible to create body below given restrictions mentioned ???

      //var paramExpr=Expresison.Parameter(typeof(Type));
      //Expression body=.................



      //compiledLambdaExpression=Expression.Lambda<Func<Type,object>>(
         //body,paramExpr).Compile();        
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe show some code of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293905/reflection-getting-the-generic-parameters-from-a-system-type-instance) what you're trying to do?

Comment: @smead code provided.  This is an expression tree question.

Comment: I don't think this is how you use linq's expressions. Accessors are fast because they are compiled for each type separately. If you're going to have type-agnostic code inside the accessor, it's not going to be better than `NormalGetFieldValue`.

Comment: @GSerg It was an exercise in playing with expression trees, was making sure there was nothing that I had missed.